# xcode enterprise provisioning

Tags: xcode, provisioning, ios-provisioning

So we have an enterpise provisioning profile that was setup by a consultant and works fine.  But now we want to give 2 other developers the right build provisioning profiles.

We go through apples provisioning profile site building the enterprise provisioning profile that goes smoothly until downloaded and opened in xcode, we get "Valid signing identity not found".

Does anyone know of a step-by-step guide. We have tried this 10 different ways, so providing links to documentation really isn't going to be much help. We tried and read about every stackoverflow post on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is go to the other box where you are currently buidling from and export the p12 file, with a password, then email that p12 to yourself.

Open the attachment from your emamil and Double click the p12 and install it on the new machine.

Gotcha.  For some reason when I did this the original box wouldn't build anything anymore. Don't freak out. We simply had to log out of the original box, shut it down, and re-login and then it started working again.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to provide them with the private key/p12 file. Usually you will get that error when there is no matching key found in Keychain app for the certificate used in the provision profile. Hope it helps.